# 一般的に使われている csv の形式は？

Tags: csv

csv は、基本的なものでは、ただ単純にascii 文字をカンマで区切った行が並んでいますが、複雑なものになると、例えば改行やカンマ自身を含めるために、ダブルクォートでくくって文字列として扱うような形式を、見たことがあります。

一般的に使われている csv の書式ないし規格はありますか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

規格としては[RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)があります。これは

- 改行コードとして`CRLF`を使用する
- 制御文字を含むフィールドは二重引用符`"`で囲む
- 二重引用符`"`をエスケープする場合は`""`と重ねる

といったものです。

また代表的な表計算ソフトであるMicrosoft ExcelではRFC 4180に加えて以下のような制限が加わります。

- 文字コードは`Shift_JIS` (ごく最近のバージョンではUTF-8も可)
- フィールド内の改行は`LF`

特にWindowsアプリケーションではこの仕様が一般的だと思います。